# JSON is undefined when using jqGrid 3.5 in IE7

Tags: json, internet-explorer, jqgrid

I am trying to switch from jqGrid 3.4 to 3.5. On the HTML page I'm using JSON.parse and after changing the jqGrid reference to the new version I get "JSON is undefined". This is happening in IE7. I had the impression that JSON is part of Javascript in IE.

Adding an explicit reference to a [JSON implementation](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) solves the probolem of course. But I don't want to add it if it is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 has a native JSON object; I don’t think IE7 does. In any case, using the JSON.org implementation or an equivalent buys you a lot more compatibility, especially if you must continue to support older browsers.

Comment: This answer helped me as well; I was trying to find out why my `backbone.js` was throwing the same error in IE7.